# Numerical error when converting array to list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, floating-point

I'm doing quite a bit of scientific numerical integration in Python, using Numpy and `ode`. I use several arrays, and I wanted to turn a 1d array into a list for exporting and easier manipulation. Since then I've found easier and more pythonic methods without resorting to lists, but before that I have stumbled across this weird unwanted behaviour that I could not find an explanation for. I've snipped the arrays in the results but this is the entirety of the code.

If I create a range array using `arange`

`a=numpy.arange(1,20,0.2)`

the result is

`array([  1. ,   1.2,   1.4,   1.6,   ... , 19.4,  19.6,  19.8])`

But if one uses the list() method as in

`list(a)`

suddenly this turns into

`[1.0, 1.2, 1.3999999999999999, 1.5999999999999999, ..., 19.399999999999995, 19.599999999999994, 19.799999999999997]`

This is a huge error. I'm not a specialist, so I can't tell exactly how it happens. I've shown this to a person that is very knowledgeable about the specific subject of number handling in computers and they told me it's quite curious, but could not immediately identify the specific problem beside saying

> Well, it's not really an error, because 0.2 can't be represented exactly, but is almost certainly not intended! All that is the case is that those two methods are not last-bit compatible

I've searched the Internet without much success, both searching for this exact error and using keywords extracted from the above explanation. So I've decided to ask here

**Has anyone stumbled on this sort of error before? Does anyone have an in-depth explanation of what causes it?**

I'm using Python 2.7.9, inside an Anaconda environment on a CentOS 6.6 machine.

**Edit**: Obviously Stack Exchange is more clever than I am and suggests a relevant question only *after* I've written down the whole thing
[Python - Converting an array to a list causes values to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435069/python-converting-an-array-to-a-list-causes-values-to-change?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Converting an array to a list causes values to change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435069/python-converting-an-array-to-a-list-causes-values-to-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No numerical errors are being introduced when you convert the array to a list, it's simply a difference in how the floating values are represented in lists and arrays.

Calling `list(a)` means you get a list of the NumPy float types (not Python `float` objects). When printed, the shell prints more digits of the float value. NumPy arrays by default only print up to 1 decimal place of the float.

If you set the precision of NumPy arrays higher, you'll see the same values as you get in your list:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=16)
>>> a = np.arange(1, 20, 0.2)
>>> a[:10]
array([ 1.                ,  1.2               ,  1.3999999999999999,
        1.5999999999999999,  1.7999999999999998,  1.9999999999999998,
        2.1999999999999997,  2.3999999999999995,  2.5999999999999996,
        2.7999999999999998])

>>> list(a[:10])
[1.0,
 1.2,
 1.3999999999999999,
 1.5999999999999999,
 1.7999999999999998,
 1.9999999999999998,
 2.1999999999999997,
 2.3999999999999995,
 2.5999999999999996,
 2.7999999999999998]
```

It's a similar story with `a.tolist()`. Here, the NumPy float datatype is converted to a Python `float` object for the list (`float` objects are just C doubles internally, like NumPy). Both types approximate the values to the same precision and have the same representation quirks.

---

Incidentally, it's worth mentioning `linspace` for generating these types of ranges. You'll still see "inaccuracies" in the float representations, but unlike `arange` you can be sure that this function returns the endpoint exactly:

```
>>> np.linspace(1, 20, 96)
array([  1.                ,   1.2               ,   1.3999999999999999,
         1.6000000000000001,   1.8               ,   2.                ,
         ...
         19.                ,  19.1999999999999993,  19.4000000000000021,
         19.6000000000000014,  19.8000000000000007,  20.                ])
```

Comment: Interesting, I was just trying in these days to understand whether `linspace` is in general more convenient to generate a list of floating point numbers than `arange` in an array format. I've switched to it in several different points as I like more the representation it uses. It's a solace to see somebody confirming my choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you print the individual contents of the array using repr you will see the exact same output:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(1, 20, 0.2)

print(repr(a[2]))
1.3999999999999999
```

Or use an ipython shell:

```
n [2]: a = numpy.arange(1, 20, 0.2)

In [3]: a[3]
Out[3]: 1.5999999999999999

In [4]: a[2]
Out[4]: 1.3999999999999999

In [5]: a[4]
Out[5]: 1.7999999999999998
```

A python list shows the repr representation of the objects stored in the list, numpy like print in python formats the output to a certain precision.